# No RPi. module found

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

Is it only possible to find the RPi. module when I'm connected with my Raspberry. I wanted to write the program first and then load it on to my Raspberry. But I get the Error that there is no RPi. module. (I downloaded Python 3.9 version but in my Project Interpreter it's version 3.7 and PyCharm 2018.3.4)

Answer (score 2):

The RPi.GPIO module only runs on the Raspberry Pi.

You will have to create your own dummy copy if you want to develop on another computer.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue myself.

What you are after is a mock library. Give this one a go:

https://pypi.org/project/Mock.GPIO/

```
pip install Mock.GPIO
```

Just replace your import:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

with:

```
import Mock.GPIO as GPIO
```